# Microsoft Word: Set default styles

Tags: ms-word, cpu-word

I have created a number of styles that I would like to use for many of my future documents. Thus, I want to create a template or set them as default so that whenever I open Word, they are there. I tried creating a template but my styles are not there. How can I do this?

Comment: This forum is for programming questions and not product usage. You should ask your question about Styles on either the SuperUser forum or Microsoft Answers.

Comment: Rich is correct. This should  not be posted here. See http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CustomizeNormalTemplate.htm and http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/ManageStyles.htm.

Comment: What topics can I ask about here? https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic